Compare Dates SharePoint - Flow and send an email
I'm getting desperate.
I have a SharePoint library that contains a date column. Now I want to create a flow that sends an email 60 and 30 days before the due date. Actually a simple task.
But no matter what I do, I get the message that the condition does not apply.
I have already worked with variables, customized the date format, but nothing works.
Can someone please help me? THANK YOU!
I want Power Automate to take the date from the SharePoint library and compare it to the current date
